# Access - Syntax error (missing operator) in query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've the following tables:

**permissions**

[image]

**user_permissions**

[image]

**users**

[image]

When trying to run the following query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users as u 
LEFT JOIN user_permissions AS up ON u.id = up.id_user 
LEFT JOIN permissions AS p ON up.id_permission = p.id
```

I'm getting the following error:

[image]

What I'm missing?

Comment: Access SQL is picky about parentheses for JOIN clauses (they are missing in your SQL). Use the query DesignView to get correct structure then switch to SQLView. The table aliases are not necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Just changed to:
```SELECT *
FROM users INNER JOIN (permissions INNER JOIN user_permissions ON permissions.id = user_permissions.id_permission) ON users.id = user_permissions.id_user
WHERE (((users.username)='admin'));
```

Comment: Weird thing is, query would work fine without those parentheses in WHERE clause but Access generates them anyway.

Comment: Yes, access sintax it's very strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN (permissions INNER JOIN user_permissions ON permissions.id = user_permissions.id_permission) ON users.id = user_permissions.id_user WHERE (((users.username)='admin'));
```

According to @June 7 comment:

> Access SQL is picky about parentheses for JOIN clauses (they are missing in your SQL). Use the query DesignView to get correct structure then switch to SQLView. The table aliases are not necessary